# MySQL снять ограничения на количество символов

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, opencart

Поменял в MyAdmin тип строки с varchar(128) на текст. Тексту поставил ограничения 500, но оно не сработало. По прежнему стоит 128. Может я не так поменял? Менял не через запрос, а на вкладке Структура - Изменить

Comment: При редактировании столбца ставите ему тип текст и убираете длину. Нажимаете сохранить. Вы не знаете где на клавиатуре кнопка стереть? Или вы не знаете как кликнуть в нужное текстовое поле мышкой?

Comment: "По прежнему стоит 128" вы это видите в майадмине или по факту не влазит текст более 128 символов?

Comment: @DmitryKozlov по факту. в `phpMyAdmin` вроде все норм

Comment: В таком случае надо учесть, что размер поля типа текст измеряется в однобайтовых символах. и если у вас кодировка utf8, то текста влезет примерно в 2 раза меньше, а если utf8mb4 то в 4. И в ваши 500 не влезет 128 русских букв

Comment: Там не русские символы, а примерно следующее `snifnazm:tmx8NVJwOWTv0QU;77779706903;410017485041406;`

Comment: можете сделать SHOW FIELDS FROM `имя_вашей_таблицы` ?

Comment: Поставьте тип `LONGTEXT`. Если и это не поможет, то ваш случай клинический и не лечится

Comment: Тип данных `TEXT` в MySQL не имеет спецификации размера. Ограничение, даже если его указать, будет игнорироваться. Макс. длина определяется только точным типом (tinytext, mediumtext, text, longtext).

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/l_2HWJ8SIQKP0Q

Comment: а текст ошибки при вставке какой?

Comment: обрезает длинный текст до 128 символов. нет ошибки никакой вроде

Comment: Итоговую схему таблицы показать можете?

show create table <table_name>;

Comment: Сейчас заметил что в ячейке хранится 350 символов, а в opencart модуль все равно 128 выдается
https://yadi.sk/i/hCAWcmEiETzv4A

Comment: Решилось. Еще в одной таблице надо было заменить с varchar на text. В первом случае все применилось, значения хранились 350 символов, но при покупке в опенкарт - он перебрасывает значение с одной ячейки в другую, которая и ограничивала до 128

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В моем случае нужно было поменять не одну таблицу, а две (для Opencart). Входная пропускала без ограничений, а выходная обрезала до 128 символов

Comment: Метку "Opencart" к вопросу добавте